# What could be causing a "Not result defined for action" "and result error" response?

Tags: struts2

I have a web application hosted that's using struts, when i call a method, i'm receiving this error :

> Error 404: No result defined for action com.personal.app.action.MyAction and result error

I've already checked the struts.xml and my action is mapped correctly to the class.

also checked context root, the classpath, and in google i haven't found yet useful info that could point me in the direction of what could be causing this response.

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory: There is some error and you don't have error result in your configuration.

Comment: Actually re-generated another ear file, re-deployed and it worked without adding error result in xml. Maybe the code i was trying to deploy was an old version not working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the action `com.personal.app.action.MyAction` returned the response of `ERROR` as the dispatcher code and Struts2 is telling you that you don't have an action mapping defined for that named result.

You either need to:

- Define a global result named **error**.
- Define a result mapping for your action.

For the latter, it would look something like:

```xml
<action name="whatever" class="com.personal.app.action.MyAction">
  <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
  <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Hope that helps.